# Show that $i^*\omega \in \Omega^{n}(S^n)$ is an orientation form on $S^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, orientation

> Show that $i^*\omega \in \Omega^{n}(S^n)$ is an orientation form on $S^n$. Here $i:S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1} - \{0\}$ and $\omega$ is a $n$-form on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}- \{0\}$ for which $\omega_p(v_1, \dots, v_n) = \det(p,v_1, \dots, v_n).$

So to prove that this is an orientation form one needs to show that $(i^*\omega)_p \ne 0$ for every $p \in S^n$. Let $p \in S^n$ and consider $v_1, \dots,v_n \in T_pS^n$. We have that $$\begin{align*}(i^*\omega)_p(v_1, \dots, v_n) &= \omega_{i(p)}(di_p(v_1), \dots, di_p(v_n)) \\ &=  \det(i(p), di_p(v_1), \dots, di_p(v_n)).\end{align*}$$

Now to show that this determinant is non-zero is where I'm getting stuck at. What options do I have here to show that this is either negative or positive?

Comment: You do not need to take the $v_i$ to be arbitrary. Instead, pick them to be a basis for $T_pS^n$. Then you can consider the vectors $\{p,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$. If you have chosen the $v_i$ to be a basis for $T_pS^n$, what does this set give you? Think about this geometrically, for $S^2\subset\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Well the $v_j$'s are linearly independent at least @QuaereVerum

Comment: Yes. Now view them as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ via $T_pS^n\subset T_p\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\cong\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then they define an $n$-dimensional linear subspace. Furthermore, the vector $p$ is normal to the hypersurface $S^n$. So what can you say about the collection $\{p,v_1,\dots,v_n\}$?

Comment: Are you trying to get at that the set is linearly independent no matter what $p$ is? I see $p$ being the only think that would cause problems of that set not being linearly independent, but if it's always normal to $S^n$, then it cannot be expressed as linear comb of the $v_j$'s. @QuaereVerum

Comment: Well it does matter what $p$ is - namely that it's a normal vector. And yes, that's what you should use, to prove that $\omega$ is nowhere vanishing on $S^n$.

Again, I would recommend visualising this for $S^2$ or $S^1$.

Comment: Do you know that $T_pS^n = \{p\}^{\perp}$ for the usual inner product of $\Bbb R^{n+1}$? If so, do you know that if $\{a,b,c\}$ (say) are linearly independent and that $d \perp a,b,c$ is nonzero, then $\{a,b,c,d\}$ is linearly independent?

Comment: @QuaereVerum I think I got the idea. Visualizing this with $S^2$ sitting inside $\mathbb{R}^3$ we have two basis vector spanning $T_pS^2$ and $p$ normal to them. Is it now just a linear algebra fact that the determinant formed by these vectors is non-zero?

Comment: Yes it is. The determinant of a matrix is non-zero if and only if its columns form a basis for the vector space. In general, you will find that linear algebra is an essential part of differential geometry, so I would recommend brushing up on this, if it isn't fresh in your memory anymore.

Comment: Yeah it has been a while... In order for all of this to work we actually need that $\{i(p), di_p(v_1), \dots, di_p(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent and I have a feeling this needs that $di_p$ maps bases to bases which is probably not true in general. @QuaereVerum

Comment: Whenever there is a submanifold $N\subset M$, there is a canonical inclusion $TN\subset TM$. So when you take the differential $di_p$, you are just viewing the vectors in $T_pN$ that you're pushing forward, as vectors in the larger vector space $T_pM$. Hence, if they are linearly independent in $T_pN$, they are also linearly independent in $T_pM$. If you have further questions about this I'm happy to answer them but then you should perhaps message me directly, as we are discouraged from having entire conversations in the comments.